# How to count the number of recursive calls made to calculate the factorial of n in Python

Tags: python, recursion

I want to write a recursive function named `recursive_factorial(n)` that takes a non-negative integer as a parameter and calculates the result of factorial(n). The function returns a **tuple** containing the result and the number of recursive calls made, in that order.

-- The first function call **does not count** as a recursive call.

```
def recursive_factorial(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 1, 0
    else:
        value,step = recursive_factorial(n-1)
        return n * value, step + 1
```

Test and Output:

```
>> print(recursive_factorial(1))
(1, 0) --- Expected
(1, 1) --- Gotten

>> print(recursive_factorial(3))
(6, 2) --- Expected
(6, 3) --- Gotten

>> print(recursive_factorial(8))
(40320, 7) --- Expected
(40320, 8) --- Gotten
```

Comment: You're successfully counting the number of recursive calls you made. You just expected to make a different number of recursive calls.

Comment: Either change your expectations, or change your algorithm to match your expectations, but the call counting is fine.

Comment: I forgot to mention, this is what is specified - The first function call does not count as a recursive call.

Comment: And your code is successfully excluding that call from the count. You **really are** making exactly the reported number of recursive calls.

Comment: @tobias_k: The function is specified to take a non-negative integer, not a positive integer, so `if n == 1` would be an inappropriate base case. `if n <= 1` would work, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to count the number of recursive calls, your expectations are wrong since you're not counting the call with `n=1`.

To show you that with an example, let's immagine you call `recursive_factorial(3)`. The stack of calls will be

1. `recursive_factorial(3)`
2. `recursive_factorial(2)`
3. `recursive_factorial(1)`
4. `recursive_factorial(0)`

Since you said you're not counting the case with `n=0`, the expected count should be 3, not 2 as you would have expected

If you want the counter to match the current expectation you have to add another base case

```
def recursive_factorial(n):
if n == 0 or n ==1:
    return 1, 0
else:
    value,step = recursive_factorial(n-1)
    return n * value, step + 1
```